# Find all Functions so that $f(1) = 1$ and $f(2) = 2$

Tags: combinatorics, functions, discrete-mathematics

Let $F$ denote the set of all functions from $A=\{1, 2, 3, 4\}$ to $B=\{1, 2, 3, ..., 10\}$.

Find and simplify the number of functions $f \in F$ so that $f(1) = 1$ and $f(2) = 2.$

**My attempt to answer:**

So, first of all, there are $n^n$ functions possible from n element set to n element set, correct? So in this case, there are a maximum of $10^4$ = 1000 possible functions from set $A$ to $B$.

Now, how many of those functions satisfy the criteria $f(1) = 1$ and $f(2) = 2$? I need some hints to answer this question. And some explanations please.

Comment: Hint: $10^4$ comes from choosing a member of $B$ four times.

Comment: Hint: You only need to count the possibilities for $F(3)$ and $F(4)$.

Comment: @hardmath if I do that, I get 100, correct? But, what about f(1) = 1, and f(2) = 2, why don't we include these two functions as well?

Comment: You only have one choice for those values, or as some would say, no choice about those.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is:
$$\large 10\cdot 10 = 100$$
**Explantion:** 
To define a function from $A$ to $B$ you need to define $f$ on all its domain, namely $A$. This means that for each element $a\in A$ you have to choose an element $b\in B$ and set $f(a)=b$. In other words, you need to choose $b_1,b_2,b_3,b_4\in B$ such that $f(1)=b_1,f(2)=b_2,f(3)=b_3,$ and $f(4)=b_4$. This defines a function from $A$ to $B$. Now, you have the constraint $f(1)=1$ and $f(2)=2$, so you may only choose only $2$ elements out of $4$ to define a function from $A$ to $B$. Since you have $10$ choice for each element, the answer is $10\cdot 10 = 100$.

Comment: thanks - but I have a question. There are a total of $10^4$ possible functions from set A to B, correct? Now, we are told that f(1) = 1, and f(2) = 2. That means, we can only choose 1 element in B for f(1), and 1 element in B for f(2). For the remaining elements, 3 and 4 in A, we have 10 choices each, that is 100. But a total should be 102 to include f(1) and F(2), 1 choice each which results to 1 function each. Right?

Comment: @Samim the number of functions is given by (nb of choice for $b_1$)${\color{red}\cdot} $(nb of choice for $b_2$)${\color{red}\cdot}$ (nb of choice for $b_3$)${\color{red}\cdot}$ (nb of choice for $b_4$) which is $1\cdot 1 \cdot 10 \cdot 10 = 100$ and not $10\cdot 10+1+1$.

Comment: So it is 1C1 X 1C1 X 10C1 X 10C1?

Comment: @Samim what do you mean by $C1$?

Comment: 1 Choose 1 x 1 Choose 1 X 10 Choose 1 X 10 Choose 1. So 10 Choose 1 = 10! / 1! (10 - 1)! = 10

Comment: Well you can write it like that but it is somehow over complication in this case. Think that you have four slots that you should fill with some number between $1$ and $10$. The first one you have to fill it with $1$, the second you have to fill it with $1$, the third one you can choose whatever and fourth one whatever between $1$ and $10$ again. So you have $1$ choice, $1$ choice, $10$ choices and $10$ choices which makes $1\cdot 1 \cdot 10 \cdot 10$ "quadruples" (or 100 different pairs if you consider that you only have to define $f(3)$ and $f(4)$).

Answer (score 3):

The number of functions $f : A \to B$ from an $n$ element set $A$ to an $m$ element set $B$ is $m^n$.

If we fix two points, we just have to count the number of ways $f$ can send the remaining points of $A$ to $B$.

So, we just have to count the number of functions from an $n-2$ element set to an $m$ element set.

Comment: Thanks @Patrick - so, so $10^2$, so 100 possible functions. But can you explain why this is?

Comment: We know that $f(1) = 1$ and $f(2) = 2$. How many ways can we send $\{3,4\}$ to $\{1,2,3,\dots,10\}$? This is just the number of functions between these two sets.

Comment: Okay, there are $10^2$ ways we can send {3, 4} to {1, ..., 10}. So, that is 100, plus the f(1) and f(2), that is 102 possible functions?

Comment: No, $f(1) = 1$ and $f(2) = 2$ for all of the 100 functions you have counted. So that would be double counting. You are just counting the ways to assign values to $f(3 )$ and $f(4)$. There are 10 choices for each value, so $100 = 10 \cdot 10$ functions in total.

Comment: Thanks for explaning, but I am still not 100% clear. So, can I say that, if A was {1, 2}, and f(1) = 1, f(2) = 2, then we only had 2 possible functions? If that is true, then for the remaining elements, 3 and 4, we have another 100 functions, sorry I find this a bit hard to grasp. Appreciate if you explain more.